# When updating an app, will it completely clean and rebuild?

Tags: xcode, updates

I am updating an app. I have many images I have changed but used the same name. For example: image.png was deleted from the project and I replaced with image.png (as to not modify the code). Will the update completely clean and rebuild or will the images not be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will

One good advice is to use `Option-Shift-Command-K` `⌥⇧⌘K` to Clean then rebuild just to make sure